# SSH 2FA not working with Google Authenticator

Tags: ssh, google-authenticator

Ssh with 2FA using Google Authenticator worked well for many months. My cellphone broke and I had to use the backup codes. All backup codes were used.

I fixed the phone, I'm able to use the Google Authenticator, but the codes don't work. I tried using the 'Time correction for codes' but it didn't help.

The administrator of the servers can't access the root account of the server (they are using VMWare but they don't know how to login as root without the password, yes, they are a little stupid).

So, I can't access the server. What can I do, consider my limitations?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want ,GoogleAuthenticate 2fa?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score -2):

I don't see a way besides reset root's password.

To reset root's password: reboot the host, edit Grub boot options and add `init=/bin/bash` to the kernel line. This will drop you into a bash command prompt where you can run `passwd` to reset the password

See this full guide with images [here](https://linuxconfig.org/recover-reset-forgotten-linux-root-password).

After successfully reset of root's password, reconfigure Google Authenticator for your user.

---

P.S:

[Authy](https://authy.com/) is a good alternative for Google Authenticator. It syncs your codes between all your devices. So, if your phone gets broken or lost again you won't have these troubles anymore.

Authy has a [ssh integration](https://www.authy.com/integrations/ssh/), you may give it a try.